# C - Forward declaration for struct and function

Tags: c, struct, typedef, forward-declaration

I'm trying to figure out how exactly forward declarations interact. When forward declaring a function that takes a typedef'd struct, is there a way to just get the compiler to accept a previously forward declared (but not actually defined) struct as a parameter?

The code that I've got working:

```
typedef struct{
  int year;
  char make[STR_SIZE];
  char model[STR_SIZE];
  char color[STR_SIZE];
  float engineSize;
}automobileType;

void printCarDeets(automobileType *);
```

What I wish I could do:

```
struct automobileType;
void printCarDeets(automobileType *);

//Defining both the struct (with typedef) and the function later
```

I feel like I'm either missing something really basic or not understanding how the compiler deals with forward declarations of structs.

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but nobody has mentioned that this is one of the differences between C and C++.  In C you can have a typedef, a struct, a union and an enum with the same name - in C++ you can only have one because it treats the tagname like C does a typedef.

Answer (score 5):

Typedefs and struct names are in different namespaces.  So `struct automobileType` and `automobileType` are not the same thing.

You need to give your anonymous struct a tag name in order to do this.

The definition in your .c file:

```
typedef struct automobileType{
  int year;
  char make[STR_SIZE];
  char model[STR_SIZE];
  char color[STR_SIZE];
  float engineSize;
}automobileType;
```

The declaration in your header file:

```
typedef struct automobileType automobileType;
void printCarDeets(automobileType *);
```

Comment: The C file should include the header, in which case you probably don't want to repeat the typedef, C11 notwithstanding.  The header is fine; you should just define `struct automobileType { … };` in the C file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, So aside from doing it in a .h file, I should just do it as I first had it working?

Comment: @ZacTaylor The above answer works regardless of whether the declaration and definition are in separate files.  The main issue is you can't forward declare an anonymous struct.

Comment: No.  You need a structure tag: `typedef struct automobileType automobileType;` in the header, along with `void printCarDetails(automobileType *);`.  Then in the C code, you define the structure: `struct automobileType { …your structure details… };` (and you also include the header there, and where you call the function).  What's in the answer works fine as long as you're compiling with C99; what's outlined here works with C89 and C99 as well as C11 (and works with pre-standard C too, but that shouldn't be an issue).

Comment: dbush, I'm not following? Isn't the whole point of a forward declaration for it to be empty? Or are anonymous and empty two different things?

@JonathanLeffler, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Grrr: my previous comment said "works fine as long as you're compiling with C99; what's outlined here works with C89 and C99 as well as C11"; it should have said "works fine as long as you're compiling with C11; what's outlined here works with C89 and C99 as well as C11"!  My bad!

Comment: @ZacTaylor Two different thing.  Anonymous means there's no tag name after the `struct` keyword.  Empty means the fields aren't specified.